# How to get all capitalizations of a word?

Tags: python, string, capitalization

I am trying for some time now to imagine a way to generate all possible capitalizations of a word in Python. For instance:

```
hello
Hello
HEllo
...
heLLo
...
HeLlO
```

I found some built-in functions which work on capitalization (`.capitalize()` for instance) but they seem to address typical cases (simple sentences, bibliography). I would be grateful for a hint on where to look as the `for` loops I thought of, as well as recursion were not a solution (I will not mention them here, they were so wrong)

---

**Clarification**: since between 5 and 9 people (via a put on hold, downvote and comments) need a clarification, I will try to make one, using different words.

> I have a string made up of characters from a to z (called later *word*). I would like, in Python, to get a list of the said *word*, but capitalized in all possible ways (that is, a mixture of upper case letters (like `M`) and lower case ones (like `f`). This leads to a list similar to the one above (with variations of the *word* `hello`.

I am sure glad I did not ask how to multiply two numbers, I would have need to clarify with a crash course in algebraic rings.

Comment: What real-life problem is addressed by this question?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do? -- What's your end goal, OP?

Comment: Not sure what is not clear in my question: having a word, I would like to have an algorythm to get a list of all capitalizations of this word. In Python. The real-life problem is that I want to get that list (because I need it for something completely unrelated to the question).  I would be happy to clarify, but I do not know what to further clarify here.

Comment: 2 to the power of the amount of the letters in the word?

Comment: @Wolf: ok ok, thank you very much. I corrected the typo which as clearly too big of a barrier for some.

Comment: Where does this string you have come from? What do you want to do with the permutations of it?

Comment: @Wolf: for instance from input, or from a file, or whatever. It does not matter. I have a word in a variable, I want to get a list of the capitalizations of that word. The accepted answer does exactly this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
for chars in itertools.product('hH', 'eE', 'lL', 'lL', 'oO'):
    print(''.join(chars))
```

OR

```
word = 'hello'
for chars in itertools.product(*zip(word, word.upper())):
    print(''.join(chars))
```

output:

```
hello
hellO
helLo
helLO
heLlo
heLlO
heLLo
heLLO
...
```

Comment: +1, Only thing I would add is that this can be written as a one-liner with a list comprehension: `[''.join(l) for l in itertools.product('hH','eE', 'lL', 'lL', 'oO')]`

Answer (score 0):

When reinterpreting the *get* of the question, it could also mean:

How to evaluate input from a **keybord with a broken shift key** (provided case doesn't matter)?

Then, I'd probably try this

```
import re

m = re.match(user_input, "hello", re.IGNORECASE);
```

...or just this

```
user_input.lower() == "hello"
```